# How to do a timer based update to a text view on Android

Tags: android, timer, textview

I need to display a text view that updates every second for 10 seconds (as a count down for instance) on an Android app.
So what I want to achieve is something like this (boiling it down to simplest elements):

```
   i = 10;
   while (i-- > 0) {
     myTextDesc.setText("Countdown " + i);
     Thread.sleep(1000); // this is in a try catch block in actual code
   }
```

However this does not appear to work at all, not sure if the `Thread.sleep()` is a problem. If I just have one `myTextDesc.setText("..some text")`, that text is showing correctly but the entire loop does not work. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated. I did search a bit on stackoverflow but did not see anything related.

Comment: are you running this code in a thread??

Comment: Its in the UI thread by posting to the Handler. That would be the only thread where UI updates are allowed right?

Comment: So what is happening? does the text is showing or the last value of i is showing in text field??

Comment: @Zoain is right you are updating it to fast 1000 means 1sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that a CountDownTimer worked perfectly for my situation. Its not clear why the snippet I posted does not work but in any case thanks for all the replies.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call `invalidate` :

```
myTextDesc.setText("Countdown " + i);
myTextDesc.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        // do the task you want to do every specified time interval
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 5000); // execute in every 5000
                                                    // ms
```

Answer (score 0):

You are updating your value in every 1000 ms means every second which is to fast to see.
Make it 10,000 and than you  can see the changes

```
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

Comment: Not a good idea to sleep the UI thread to 10 seconds, which will result in ANR....Google if you don't know.

Answer (score 0):

```
int counter =30;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable countDownRunnable=new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        counter--;
        if(counter<0){
            //Count down ends
        }else{
            // Update Textview here.
            mHandler.postDelayed(countDownRunnable, 10000);//10 seconds
        }

    }
};

private void startCountDown(){
    counter=30; //Count down start
    mHandler.post(countDownRunnable);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   final Handler h = new Handler();
    h.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

             long millis =(long)currentTime(); // Get time in millis     
             dateAndTime.setText(getDate(millis, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS"));  // To human readable time

             h.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mTimerHandler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
```

......

```
    Handler mTimerHandler = new Handler();
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mLeftTimeSeconds--;
        if (mLeftTimeSeconds > 0) {
            int minus = mLeftTimeSeconds / 60;
            int seconds = mLeftTimeSeconds % 60;
 // do you things
            mTimerHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }

};
```